# localhost port blocking on all browsers (using windows 10, 64 bit)

Tags: browser, windows-10, localhost, port

I am using a web-browser just to display data from my application ... example URL would be something like http://localhost:11234 (11234 is a listener port, btw http://127.0.0.1:11234 isn't working either) ... that worked fine until about 1 week ago, and all of a sudden, when trying to do this ... it tries to open but just goes into an endless loop. The local-host seems to be known... so for example:

> C:\Users\snafo\Desktop>ping localhost

```
 Pinging box5 [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from ::1: time<1ms
 Reply from ::1: time<1ms
 Reply from ::1: time<1ms
 Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

Ping statistics for ::1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milliseconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Also "nestat" shows the port is listening correctly:

TCP    127.0.0.1:63803        box5:11234             ESTABLISHED

But any browser just rotates endlessly (if i would use a wrong port accidently, the browsers would tell me sth like "... can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:11234")
I can take any random port, problem stays. Disabling the antivirus(Avast) does not help either.

Any ideas??

Just one point: when I open DOS i get:
"The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2350 in the message file for Application" .. in other words sth. was changed. The problem above started at the same time ..